# Ralink 802.11n WLAN Greyed out

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I'm going to need to start using the WiFi on my Ubuntu system soon but my onboard WiFi is very slow and bad. However, Ubuntu is not letting me use my WiFi card. I'm not really sure what to do, I have tried looking into the issue and install drivers, etc., without success. I typed in the command `rfkill` and this is what it shows:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also when I do `sudo lshw -C network`, this is what that shows:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface  /// this is the one i need working
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: 74:d4:35:9e:28:9c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.041.00-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fddff000-fddfffff memory:fddf8000-fddfbfff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros /// this is my on-board ,so i cant use it.
       physical id: 6
       bus info: pci@0000:04:06.0
       logical name: wlp4s6
       version: 01
       serial: e8:94:f6:57:42:e3
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-98-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.49 latency=168 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:20 memory:fdcf0000-fdcfffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: ham0
       serial: 7a:79:19:10:87:c8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.16.135.200 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlxdc85de4a57c1
       serial: dc:85:de:4a:57:c1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.4.0-98-generic firmware=0.29 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have not tried using the WiFi card before, however I know the card itself works on my Windows system.
I'm kind of clueless as to what is wrong at this point so if anyone could please help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: Edited and waiting approval. A tip: Code should be posted as code: Select it and use {}. For images click the picture icon. The rest, honestly, is just laziness. Please make proper sentences with the proper capitalization where's required.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.